# geolocalizacion html y js en chrome android

Tags: javascript, html, geolocalización

resulta que estoy tratando de visualizar las coordenadas de geolocalizacion con js y html
en el navegador chrome de pc  me muestra el permiso y las coordenadas de forma correcta pero cuando me dirijo al de android no pasa nada y lo que me gustaria es que funcione tanto para el navegador de pc y android

este es mi codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Geolocalizacion</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
    <div id="out"></div>
    
    
<script>

function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  output.innerHTML = "<p>si</p>";
} else {
  output.innerHTML = "<p>NO</p>";
}


if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mostrarUbicacion);
}

function mostrarUbicacion (ubicacion) {
  const lng = ubicacion.coords.longitude;
  const lat = ubicacion.coords.latitude;
  output.innerHTML = lng;
}

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que para poder que puedas utilizar la ubicacion tienes que encontrarte en un entorno seguro, es decir una direccion que contenga cierta seguridad, por ejemplo una ruta con protocolo HTTPS (HTTP no vale), tampoco se considera segura las rutas por medio de direccion ip por lo que esas tampoco valen, en pocas palabras tendrias que descargar el sitio en el celular y abrir la pagina desde el celular como si fuera un archivo, ya que el protocolo `file://` si que se considera seguro segun los navegadores.

Comment: Y obviamente cabe aclarar que tienes que tener la ubicacion prendida xd, revisalo porque una vez tenia un error bastante tonto que no me dejaba progresar, pero luego descubri que era simplemente por que la ubicacion nunca se resolvia...

Comment: Bueno al parecer era por el protocolo tenias razón  muchas gracias por la información

Comment: De nada, por cierto, el `localhost` cuenta como seguro, sin embargo al tratarse del celular como no se puede acceder a `localhost` directamente no te dije esa opcion, sin embargo si estuvieras trabajando en la pc verias que puedes obtener la ubicacion usando `localhost`, es util que sepas esto para que no tengas que ponerte a crear certificados `HTTPS` para hacer pruebas que requieran de seguridad, pues `localhost` los navegadores lo consideran seguros.

Comment: Si estoy usando un host que ya cuenta con certificados entonces lo hace mas fácil gracias por la info

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un código que hice el año pasado para alguien que tenía el mismo problema que tú. Funciona (o funcionaba) en localhost y te avisa de cual es el problema si falla. (Debes dar permisos).

```
﻿<html>
<body>
<script>var Geolocalizacion = navigator.geolocation || (window.google && google.gears && google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation'));
if (Geolocalizacion) Geolocalizacion.getCurrentPosition(MuestraLocalizacion, Excepciones);
  
function MuestraLocalizacion(posicion) {
alert(posicion.coords.latitude);
alert(posicion.coords.longitude);
alert(posicion.coords.accuracy);
}
  
function Excepciones(error) {
   switch (error.code) {
   case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      alert('Activa permisos de geolocalizacion');
      break;
   case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert('Activa localizacion por GPS o Redes .');
      break;
   default:
      alert('ERROR: ' + error.code);
    }
  }</script>
</body>
</html>
```

También puedes usar una api que haga la geoloc en base a la ip. Será menos precisa y menos confiable pero no necesita permisos y puedes requerir ips de otros.
Ejemplo de ip-api.com con mi ip:
http://ip-api.com/json/176.87.16.80